# Is it possible to make a code like Join two tables with PHP code

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having problems, I need a query to join table with two database and the database of each different network. Example **ABC database** in network 192.168.1.1 and **database EFD** in network 192.168.1.2
I've tried and ask other people, they say it's impossible.
So there are other ways to join in array php code?
So an example like this:

A array from **databases ABC table glass** is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Glass one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Glass two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Glass three
        )

)
```

A array from **database EFD table price** is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [glass_id] => 1
            [price] => $50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [glass_id] => 2
            [price] => $30
        )

)
```

And then I want to combine the two arrays above based **id** in array one with **glass_id** in array two. And then I want to get a result as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Glass one
            [price] => $50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Glass two
            [price] => $30
        )

)
```

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Comment: You won't be able to run a query across two servers, but you can have connections to both servers open simultaneously. Then just run two queries and combine with one of PHPs `array_` functions.

Comment: @MikeW : Yeah, the above is such that.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
  $array1 = array("make","model","color","year");
  $array2 = array("Jeep","Liberty","Black","2005");
  $newArray = array_combine($array1, $array2);
  foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 
  }
```

try like this one.

Comment: use code formatting in future, please. Your sample doesn't fit on question. I also think that using array_intersect is much more efficient.